# SwiftPM: How to setup Swift module.map referring to two connected C libraries

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, module-map

I'm trying to build a Swift Package Manager system package (a module.modulemap)
making available two system C libraries where one includes the other.

That is, one (say libcurl) is a base module and the other C library is including 
that (like so: `#include "libcurl.h"`). On the regular C side this works, because
the makefiles pass in proper `-I` flags and all is good (and I could presumably
do the same in SPM, but I'd like to avoid extra flags to SPM).

So what I came up with is this module map:

```
module CBase [system] {
  header "/usr/include/curl.h"
  link "curl"
  export *
}

module CMyLib [system] {
  use CBase
  header "/usr/include/mylib.h"
  link "mylib"
  export *
}
```

I got importing `CBase` in a Swift package working fine.
But when I try to import `CMyLib`, the compiler complains:

```
error: 'curl.h' file not found
```

Which is kinda understandable because the compiler doesn't know where to look 
(though I assumed that `use CBase` would help).

Is there a way to get this to work w/o having to add `-Xcc -I` flags to the
build process?

Update 1: To a degree this is covered in 
[Swift SR-145](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-145)
and
[SE-0063: SwiftPM System Module Search Paths](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0063-swiftpm-system-module-search-paths.md).
The recommendation is to use the Package.swift `pkgConfig` setting. This seems to work OK for my specific setup. However, it is a chicken and egg if there is no `.pc` file. I tried embedding an own `.pc` file in the package, but the system package directory isn't added to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (and hence won't be considered during the compilation of a dependent module). So the question stands: how to accomplish that in an environment where there libs are installed, but w/o a `.pc` file (just header and lib).